# Getting your position with {{#each}}

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to figure out whether there's a way to get my position during a looped render using {{#each}}.  Hacking at the source, there doesn't appear to be an easy way to do it - but that may be simply a result of my inability to trace well through the code.

Answer (score 1):

contentIndex will be set on the view on creation but will NOT be updated as the array mutates.

Comment: Is there any way to force it to update? This is exactly what I'm trying to do...

Comment: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/4095